# How do I list all filenames starting with '#...' in ksh?

Tags: ksh, ls

Some of the files in a dir are of the form '#a', '#b'. How do I list (using 'ls') only these files and exclude others such as abc.txt?

I've tried various quoting syntax but unable to achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#` has to be quoted, to prevent rest of the line from being treated as a comment, but the wildcards must *not* be quoted, to allow for pathname expansion. Ergo,

```
ls "#"*
```

Since quotes are just a way of escaping entire sequences of characters, you can also save a character and simply write

```
ls \#*
```

Comment: Thank you. Based on your solution, I realized that I mistook the single quotes as part of the filenames. It looks like these single quotes were added by the ksh for displaying purpose.